# Partially aggregate (sum) values that are below the first n observations in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a dataframe like **df**:

```
id <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj")
value <- c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, value)
```

I want to aggregate the values that are rank below n-th position (in this case, n=5), such that, the new data looks like **df_new**:

```
id_new <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "others") 
value_new <- c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 15)
df_new <- data.frame(id_new, value_new)
```

I have tried to combine `top_n` with `summarise` in dplyr but I do not find the way to aggregate a dataset partially.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to utilize the `fct_lump_n` in `forcats` (part of `tidyverse`):

The idea is to treat id as a factor with x levels, `fct_lump_n` lumps all but `n` into the same factor. We could then use `count` to summarize all the *others*-factor-level into one. I.e.

```r
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(id = fct_lump_n(as.factor(id), n = 5, w = value, other_level = "others")) |>
  count(id, wt = value, name = "value")
```

Or use a similar logic with `dplyr` alone: As we have no value-weighting in the first place, we'll need to arrange before recoding.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  arrange(desc(value)) |> 
  mutate(id = if_else(row_number() > 5, "others", id)) |>
  count(id, wt = value, name = "value")
```

Output:

```
      id value
1     aa    10
2     bb     9
3     cc     8
4     dd     7
5     ee     6
6 others    15
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there are that there are more elegant ways, but you could just split the operation into two separat ones and then combine the resulting data frames. Something like this should work:

```
tmp1<-df %>% 
  slice_max(value, n=5)

tmp2<-df %>% 
  slice_min(value,n=nrow(.)-5) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(others=sum(value)) %>%
  t() %>% 
  enframe(name = "id", value = "value")

out_df<-rbind(tmp1,tmp2)
```